# XMLReader skips every other node

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, xml-parsing

I've been searching for similar problem, but every of those are simple to resolve (double reader.Read() method), but mine is very odd...

Here is my ASP.NET C# method:

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> getXMLData(String inputURI, String elementName)
    {
        List<XElement> result = new List<XElement>();
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputURI);
        XElement elem;

        reader.MoveToContent();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name.Equals(elementName))
                {
                    elem = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                    if (elem != null)
                    {
                        result.Add(elem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am trying to parse following URI:
http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/aapl/chartdata;type=quote;range=1m/

And Im selecting elemName="p" - theese are values to my jqplot chart, by the way.

Problem is, that this parsing method saves to list every other "p" node; there are 20 "p" nodes in this XML file, but my parser only saves 10 element (every other, starts from first);

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A neater solution might look like this -

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string s = client.DownloadString("http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/aapl/chartdata;type=quote;range=1m/");
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(s);
    var result = xDoc.Descendants("p").ToList();

    return result;

}
```

replace the URL with the URL string passed into the method to make it more generic.

Comment: It's an old post but very useful